# Questions on build a web app android

Tags: android, build, web

I'm trying to build an android app (with the latest eclipse) that display my site (that is hosted by blogfree) using webview;

here's my question:

- How can I implement the accelerometer (so when the screen is moved in landscape the app is resized)?
- I have set the permision for internet, but the app can acces it only with wifi or with datamobile too?
- Is there a way to use button that redirect to a webpage (ex. a button named youtube that when is clicked it display my youtube channel)?

Answer (score 0):

1. Android app automatically resized if you dont want to change your app orientation mode you can set its orientation.
   for more refrences:https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screen-compat-mode.html

   ```
   <activity
       android:name=".Activities.ScreenSharing"
       android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
   ```

2.)Internet permission is avaliable for both mobile+wifi data.

3.) Yes you can use a button to redirect to any webpage. 
Create a button:

```
   Webview wv1;
   Button b= (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
    b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
          //call your web page

        wv1.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
        wv1.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        wv1.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
        wv1.loadUrl(url);

        }
    });
```